# How to show real-time in face detection on a frame in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, face-detection, face-recognition

I have made face detection in python using OpenCV,
I want to add real-time (AM and PM ) on a frame in red colour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get current date and time

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
```

Add a text rectangle in Frame

```
# Draw a rectangle around the text
ori = cv2.rectangle(img,(10,180), (500,300), (0,0,255), 4)
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
cv2.putText(ori,'Put-Your-Format-Here',(30,256), font, 2.5,(255,255,255),2,cv2.LINE_AA)
```